# How to enable “Siri Knowledge” suggestion in Safari?

Tags: siri, mobile-safari, ios

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/6yxdgb/is_siri_knowledge_new_feature/) shows a new suggestion in Safari called “Siri Knowledge”, located above “Google Search”:

[image: screenshot]

However, it seems the post talks about beta version of iOS 11, and some commenters didn’t have this feature. On my iOS 11.0.1 on iPhone 6, I don’t see it too.

Was this feature included in iOS 11 final release version, and, if yes, then how to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS11.1 you can control the display of “Siri Knowledge” in Safari by toggling:

**Settings->Safari->Safari Suggestions**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences -> Siri -> Siri Suggestions & Privacy, then check Safari. Tested under macOS 10.13

Comment: Sorry, but the question was about iOS.